# Combinatorics with repetition issue

Tags: combinatorics

I have trouble with the following kind of problem:

You have 31 black pillows, 11 pink pillows and 40 white pillows. In how many ways you can choose exactly  20 pillows.

This is a combinatorics problem with repetition constrained.
I tried 
$$
{{82}\choose{20}} \times \frac{1}{31} \times \frac{1}{11} \times \frac{1}{40}
$$

or

$$
{{82}\choose{20}} \times \frac{1}{31!} \times \frac{1}{11!} \times \frac{1}{40!}
$$

That does not seem to get the right result. How should I approach this. Thanks!

Comment: But whats the constraint

Comment: Count all as if no constrain exist, and after quit the invalid combinations, i.e., the combinations with more than 11 pink.

Comment: Suppose you chose 10 black pillows and 10 white pillows. Does it matter _which_ 10 black pillows you chose? If not, the number of black pillows you had to choose from does not matter. If it _does_ matter, i.e. you have 82 pillows somehow distinguishable in ways other than just color, then you just have 82 pillows to choose from and all the stuff about how many of each color is just a distraction. I would guess that 10 black pillows, 10 white pillows is supposed to count as just one choice regardless of which particular black pillows you chose.

Answer (score 3):

One clean way to set up such problems is to use generating functions. As the number of black and white pillows are larger than $20$, take them as infinite:

$\begin{align}
1 + z + z^2 + \dotsb = \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

For the pink pillows, it is:

$\begin{align}
1 + z + \dotsb + z^{11} = \frac{1 - z^{12}}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

For all, you want the coefficient of $z^{20}$ in the product of the above:

$\begin{align}
  [z^{20}] \frac{1}{1 - z}
             \cdot \frac{1 - z^{12}}{1 - z}
             \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
    &= [z^{20}] \frac{1 - z^{12}}{(1 - z)^3} \\
    &= [z^{20}] (1 - z^{12}) \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-3}{k} z^k \\
    &= [z^{20}] (1 - z^{12}) 
         \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} z^k \\
    &= ([z^{20}] - [z^8]) \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} z^k \\
    &= \binom{22}{2} - \binom{10}{2} \\
    &= 186
\end{align}$

The same method clearly works for cases in which all pillow numbers are limited, and cases in which you have e.g. some pillows that only can be in even numbers or such.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I take pillows of the same color to be identical,
as else mentioning colors would be meaningless.

Now imagine that you are putting identical pillows into colored boxes, and that they magically acquire the color of the box into which put! The problem reduces to putting identical objects into distinguishable boxes, which you will recognize as a stars and bars type.

Without restrictions, there would be $= \binom{20+3-1}{3-1}$ ways,

but we have a restriction of maximum $11$ pink pillows, so to count invalid distributions to be subtracted, we pre-place $12$ pillows in the pink box. Now all ways of distributing the balance $8$ will be invalid,

yielding the final answer of $\binom{20+3-1}2 - \binom{8+3-1}2$

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this problem is with distributions. We disregard the number of white and black pillows, as they are both larger than the $20$ we have to select. Thus, we are only concerned with the number of pink pillows. Since there are only $11$ of these, let us count with respect to $p,$ the number of pink pillows. Knowing that the number of ways to distribute $k$ types for a total of $n$ objects is
$$\dbinom{n + k - 1}{k - 1},$$
we can write a summation for our count.

We can write the summation
$$\sum_{p = 0}^{11} \dbinom{(20 - p) + 2 - 1}{2 - 1}$$
$$= \sum_{p = 0}^{11} (21 - p)$$
$$= \boxed{186}.$$

Comment: This is a nice approach.  I suggest placing the $21 - p$ is parentheses to make it clear what the summands are.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You need to calculate the number of ways for writing $20$ as a sum of $3$ non-negative integers, such that the second integer is not larger than $11$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be the number of black pillows; let $p$ be the number of pink pillows; let $w$ be the number of white pillows.  Then we want the number of solutions of the equation 
$$b + p + w = 20 \tag{1}$$
in the non-negative integers subject to the constraints $b \leq 31$, $p \leq 11$, and $w \leq 40$.  Since the number of available black pillows and white pillows both exceed the number of pillows we need, the only constraint we need to consider is that $p \leq 11$.

A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the insertion of two addition signs in a row of $20$ ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $b = 12$, $p = 0$, and $w = 8$, while
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $b = 6$, $p = 10$, and $w = 4$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways two addition signs can be inserted into a row of twenty ones, which is 
$$\binom{20 + 2}{2} = \binom{22}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the $22$ symbols ($20$ ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.

From these, we must exclude those solutions in which the number of pink pillows exceeds $11$.

Suppose $p > 11$.  Let $p' = p - 12$.  Then $p$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $p' + 12$ for $p$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
b + p' + 12 + w & = 20\\
b + p' + w & = 8 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers with 
$$\binom{8 + 2}{2} = \binom{10}{2}$$
solutions.

Hence, the number of ways of selecting $20$ pillows from $31$ black pillows, $11$ pink pillows, and $40$ white pillows is 
$$\binom{22}{2} - \binom{10}{2}$$